# Most efficient limit the maximum number of users on a webpage

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

We need to limit the maximum amount of users on some of our webpages in our webapp.
We were thinking to create the following logic:

1. User visits a webpage
2. In middleware we check if the route is limited.
3. If the route is limited we check the number of records in a database table dedicated to log page visits.
4. If the dedicated table has more rows for the page than the limit count, we block the request
5. If the user leaves the page, we remove its record (again checked in middleware)

Is this efficient or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried that? And was it efficient enough?

Comment: How do you know, the user leaves the page? What happens if I close the browser window or kill the browser process?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? HTTP doesn't have persistent connections. When a user requests a page the connection is closed once the page is returned. Throttling works at the connection level because it simply doesn't make sense to throttle at the "page" level. UNLESS you have an SPA which keeps polling the server. Again, this is about requests though, not pages.

Comment: If you have a polling issue a possible solution is to *not* use polling. Use SignalR, WebSockets or SSEs instead to send notifications to all clients on that page for example. You can limit the number of "subscribers" if you want in all cases.

Comment: You need to handle this at the load balancer level.